# How to use different cell alignments in the same row?

Tags: tables, alignment, makecell

Using \makecell, I would like the first column of each row to be centered, centered (cc) but the remaining columns to be top, left (tl). Is this possible?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcommmand\tab{\hspace{10mm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|R{1in}|R{1in}|R{1in}|R{1in}|}
 Test Header & Test Header & Test Header & Test Header \\
 \hline
 \makecell[cc]{Row 1} 
 & \makecell[tl]{Item 1 \\ \tab Value} 
 & \makecell[tl]{Item 2 \\ \tab Value \\ Item 3 \\ \tab Value} 
 & \makecell[tl]{Item 4 \\ \tab Value \\ Item 5 \\ \tab Value \\ Item 6 \\ \tab Value} \\
 \hline
 \makecell[cc]{Row 2} 
 & \makecell[tl]{Item 1 \\ \tab Value} 
 & \makecell[tl]{Item 2 \\ \tab Value \\ Item 3 \\ \tab Value} 
 & \makecell[tl]{Item 4 \\ \tab Value \\ Item 5 \\ \tab Value \\ Item 6 \\ \tab Value} \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So you're looking for something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sUOM.png) (I've used [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for the presentation)?

Comment: Yes! Could you share the code you used for that?

Comment: I used [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/vZHqJ7Pi). If it suits your needs, I can post it as an answer. Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy with the `tblr` environment provided by `tabularray` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
            hlines,
            %vlines, % uncomment if you really want vertical lines
            columns={1in, l, h}, % default left and head alignment
            column{1}={c, m}, % column1 horizontal and vertical centered
        }
        Test Header & Test Header & Test Header & Test Header \\
        Row 1
        & {Item \\ Value}   
        & {Item 2 \\ Value \\ Item 3 \\ Value} 
        & {Item 4 \\ Value \\ Item 5 \\ Value \\ Item 6 \\ Value} \\
        Row 2
        & {Item 1 \\ Value} 
        & {Item 2 \\ Value \\ Item 3 \\ Value} 
        & {Item 4 \\ Value \\ Item 5 \\ Value \\ Item 6 \\ Value} \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: table output]

Inside `tblr` environment, you can just enclose entries with `{}` and use `\\` for linebreaks as usual.